How to extract and reveal code from SQL database in Wordpress
I have had to stop using a particular plugin (php everywhere) for security and no recent updates issues. However I would like to retrieve the code which was stored against that plugin which I have got from the WP_Posts table.
The problem is that it is encoded somehow, I thought UTF but that does not seem to produce anything. The first part is like this:
JTNDJTNGcGhwJTBBZ2xvY
Can anyone suggest what encoding this might be and how to convert it to ordinary text?

it's encoded in base64. if you try rawurldecode(base64_decode("JTNDJTNGcGhwJTBBZ2xvY")) you obtain <?php glo.
